# PHP multiply column of multidimensional array and get sum of result

Tags: php

Very basically you suppose I have this arrays:

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [4,5,6];
```

and now I want to `Multiply` the numbers of columns, for example:

```
1*4
2*5
3*6
```

and get sum multiply of all calculation, for example:

```
4+10+18 = 32
```

I need to get this result, I can't implementing this scenario with `array_map` or `array_reduce`, using two `foreach` return wrong result for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This..

```
$total = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
  $total += $a[$i] * $b[$i];
}

echo $total;
```